# In Laravel can you check to see if an object is in a Collection by using the object's primary key?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I need a quick way to tell if an object is in a collection.  I'm building a template where an admin can assign a User a role.  The statement below is essentially what I'm trying to accomplish.

IS the role with a primary key value of 5 in this collection of Roles.

**What I'm doing (obviously dumbed down into one file):**

```
<?php
// The user
$user = User::find(1);

// Array of roles the user is associated with.  Fetched via a pivot table
$tmpUserRoles = $user->roles->toArray();

// Rebuilds the values from $tmpUserRoles so that the array key is the primary key
$userRoles = array();
foreach ($tmpUserRoles as $roleData) {
    $userRoles[$roleData['role_id']] = $roleData;
}

// This loop is used in the view.  Once again, this is dumbed down
foreach ($Roles as $role) {
    if (isset($userRoles[$role->role_id]) {
        echo $user->firstName.' is a '.$role->label;
    } else {
        echo $user->firstName.' is not a '.$role->label;
    }
}
```

Looping over an array just to create an identical array with the primary key as an index seems like a big waste of time.  Is there an easier way in Laravel to tell if an object is contained in a collection by using the object's primary key?

Comment: $user->roles()->find(5) adding the () after roles will query the relation set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `$tmpUserRoles->contains(5)` to check if primary key `5` exists in your collection.
(See http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#collections)

Comment: For versions 5.1+, you can use `->has()`, e.g. `$tmpUserRoles->has(5)` https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-has

Answer (score 2):

The selected answer looks like it works.

If you want a more readable way of testing if an object is an instance of the laravel collection class (or any class in general) you could use the php [`is_a()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php) function:

```
// This will return true if $user is a collection
is_a($user, "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection");
```

This doesn't do the finding that you're also wanting to do in your question description, but it could be helpful in general.

Comment: Use this instead `Illuminate\Support\Collection`

```var_dump( is_a( User::active()->get(), 'Illuminate\Support\Collection') ); // true
var_dump( is_a( User::pluck('id'), 'Illuminate\Support\Collection') ); // true```